# How can i fix this ESLint problem on Brackets

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

the problem is so easy but I can't fix it .The code is working but ESLint show some errors how can i fix that?
[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muZ6k.png)

Comment: Setting `env.browser = true` in your eslint config should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**File** > **Extension Manager** > search for brackets-eslint > install extension and enable

Comment: didn't work ...